# Quais componentes devo utilizar para seleção de cores e fotos em ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, bootstrap-3, componentes

Tenho uma solução ASP.NET usando bootstrap para estilização de páginas e gostaria de recomendações para dois tipos de componente:

Um para cores, que retorne o código da cor em hexadecimal, por exemplo: ffffff ou #ffffff;

E um para upload de fotos, se possível um que tenha uma galeria de miniaturas.
Obs: As fotos serão salvas no servidor, ou seja, não vai ter comunicação com banco de dados.

Grato.

Answer (score 2):

Pra cores tem dois: o [JSColor](http://jscolor.com/) e o [Bootstrap Color Picker](http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/).

Pra *thumbnails* você pode usar o [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/).

Para exibição dos *thumbnails*, você pode usar, combinado com o ImageResizer, o [OwlCarousel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OwlCarousel/1.3.3).

Comment: O JSColor funcionou perfeitamente, estou implementando o ImageResizer para testar mas não entendi como aplicá-lo no html. Você pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Esse componente possui algo específico para fazer o upload e tratamento das imagens?

Comment: Ele trata imagens. Upload é outra coisa. Se você quer gerar miniaturas para suas *Views* usando ImageResizer, abra outra pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Pergunta editada.

Comment: Editei a resposta também.